# Interface B/w module

Tags: php, linux, networking, ubuntu, snmp

Image : http://i40.tinypic.com/2hodx55.png

I have built a Network Interface Monitor using Php and SNMP , but now when i execute it on localhost i see my graph goes to origin(0) again and again (Please see the image) and also the speed on Y axis is wrong. At times it goes in Millons and Millions.

please can anyone tell me what is the problem in the code below

```
    <?php
     $int="wlan0";


       session_start();

  $rx0 =snmpget('localhost','public','.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.3');

 $tx0 =snmpget('localhost','public','.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.3');

  sleep(5);

 $rx1 =snmpget('localhost','public','.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.3');

 $tx1 =snmpget('localhost','public','.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.3');


   $rx0 = substr($rx0, 11);
   $tx0 = substr($tx0, 11);
   $rx1 = substr($rx1, 11);
   $tx1 = substr($tx1, 11);

   $tBps = $tx1 - $tx0;
   $rBps = $rx1 - $rx0;

   $round_rx=$rBps;
   $round_tx=$tBps;



   $time=date("U")."000";


$_SESSION['rx'][] = "[$time, $round_rx]";   
 $_SESSION['tx'][] = "[$time, $round_tx]";
  $data['label'] = $int;
     $data['data'] = $_SESSION['rx'];

          if (count($_SESSION['rx'])>60)
    {
    $x = min(array_keys($_SESSION['rx']));
     unset($_SESSION['rx'][$x]);

    }




        echo '{"label":"'.$int.'","data":['.implode($_SESSION['rx'], ",").']}';


         ?>
```

Comment: You haven't posted any data - how can we tell what's happening to it?

Comment: However In this line `$x = min(array_keys($_SESSION['rx']));` `$x` will always be zero, since you haven't assigned any keys to this array. Your `echo` statement looks like its supposed to be generating JSON - this is probably better done by creating a suitable PHP associatuve array and using `json_encode()`.

Comment: @MikeW I appreciate your reply , I have attached a link to the picture you can see there the O/p.  So how can i really assign a key and JSON isn't really working how can i change to Php?

Comment: Your picture shows your final output. For all I know, that reflects your input accurately, and your raw data is wrong. It's also possible that there's nothing wrong with your code here, and it's the software that produces the chart that's wrong.

Comment: I've posted a simplified snippet that should generate clean JSON. You need to check the raw data from `snmpget()` and the output JSON for the zero values. I don't, at present, see how they could be coming from this section of code.

Comment: @MikeW Hey man its still the same. The point is going to ORIGIN again  and then back to peak and then again origin and back to peak

Comment: I can't do anything more with this. **You** need to check your raw data and verify that it's good. **You** need to check the data leaving this code and verify that it matches the input. This is basic debugging stuff and will help pin down the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified the code in the lower part of your snippet.

- I assume `$_SESSION['rx']` is initialised to an array somewhere.
- `$data` has gone - I hope it's not used further down.
- `$_SESSION['tx']` is updated but otherwise unused, as it was in your snippet.

This should generate clean JSON output for `rx`. I don't see where the zero values are coming from in your version or in this. Check both the input to this (the raw values from `snmpget()`), and the output JSON strings.

```
$_SESSION['rx'][] = array($time, $round_rx);   
$_SESSION['tx'][] = array($time, $round_tx);

// retaining just the 60 most recent entries.
if (count($_SESSION['rx'])>60) {
  array_shift($_SESSION['rx']);
}

$rxdata = array("label"=>$int, "data"=>$_SESSION['rx']);
echo json_encode($rxdata);
```